# Sage subshell gcc error

Tags: gcc, sage

I am trying to use gcc under the subshell of Sage. Unfortunately, I am not able to start/link gcc.

For example:

```
:Fname$ sage -sh
(sage-sh) :Fname$ gcc
gcc: error: /usr/lib/sagemath//local/lib/gcc/: Is a directory
(sage-sh) :Fname$
```

What is the extra configuration I need to apply, in order to start successfully gcc under the Sage subshell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you just download a Sage binary without compiling from scratch?  Then typically compilation (including Cython) won't work.  We'd probably need more details for a more precise diagnosis; you can always build from scratch, though.

Comment: I have followed the instructions in the Ubuntu official site:

apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary

Should I try with compiling it from scratch? I mean, the compilation is working fine at the beginning if I add this custom row in "sage-env" file: export CC="/usr/bin/gcc". Then the compilation started and all #cfile's are successfully compiled, but after 3-4 minutes again the same mistake (I think I need to change somehow the PATH to the compiler?)

Comment: I don't know about that process, only from directly downloading.  But you may want to compile it.  I'm not even sure the `gcc` in Sage on a Linux binary is even more than a link to some standard place.

Comment: Also, more Sage gurus hang out at ask.sagemath.org so you may wish to try there if no one has a definitive answer here.  I don't use Sage on Linux myself, unless I compile from scratch.